# Converting any numbers to same scale using Numeral JS

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, numeral.js

Currently when using `numeral(1000000).format('0a')` will return `1m`, however is it possible to set a scale, for example `thousands`, so any number will get converted to a number in thousands?
For instance 1000000 will become 1000k, and 100 would become 0,1k and so on.

```js
console.log(
  numeral(1000000).format('0a')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `0ak` format

https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/blob/master/src/numeral.js#L143

```js
console.log("1000000:",numeral(1000000).format('0ak'),"\n100:",numeral(100).format('0ak'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry it not documented and thankyou for improvising the answer